# How do I import a library in flash which lies in a higher directory than my .fla

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
Projects ->
Libraries ->
    Box2d ->
        Collision->
        Common ->
        etc...
PlaneGame ->
    PlaneGame.fla
    main.as
```

Now I wish to import classes from Box2d but I cannot figure out how to do "up one level" which would be done like "../../something.example" in another language.

How can I include classes from inside the Box2d folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using FLash CS3, go to File -> Publish Settings.

Click on the Flash tab -> Click on the Settings button beside ActionScript version.

Then add your class path there. In your case, your class path should be something like "C:..\Libraries\Box2d"

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer :)